# Codeigniter model pass value controller to view

Tags: codeigniter, view, model, controller

Table products: id, product, lining, ...
Table tbl_lining: id, article, description

Model

```
public function getliningsale($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('tbl_lining', 'products.lining=tbl_lining.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('products.id', $id);  // Also mention table name here
    $query = $this->db->get();    
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $data->result();
}
```

Controller

```
function liningsale($id)
{   

    $data['liningsale'] = $this->sales_model->getliningsale($id);
    $this->load->view('add', $data);
}
```

View

```
echo '<td><input class="span1 tran2" name="lining\'+ count +\'" type="text"';
echo 'value="';
foreach ($liningsale as $valor) {
    echo $valor->article;
    echo '-';
    echo $valor->description; 
    echo '">';
}

echo '</td>';
```

This doesn't display any record.
I've tried several ways without success.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump($query->num_rows());` after $this->db>-get(). You can also use `echo $this->db->last_query();` and test your query in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: int(0)

What does this means?
0 rows?

`SELECT * FROM (`products`) LEFT JOIN `tbl_lining` ON `products`.`lining`=`tbl_lining`.`id` WHERE `tbl_lining`.`id` IS NULL`

Comment: In PhpMyAdmin the query didn't find any record...

Now I know that is a problem with the query. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As you see, your ID is null. So you don't pass any ID to your model function. Check if you have an ID in your URL when you call your controller.

Comment: Yeah I get that part 
This is a table of orders that loads the data via jquery (see picture here http://goo.gl/6Jl7XO)
The script was already functional. Just need to add more information to it. 
Seeking only the IDs stored in each column without JOIN, (lining / leather / others) the query is successful, with display of one only IDs per line. The problem is in `$this> db> where ('products.id', $ id);` to do the JOIN. 

I do not understand your tip. Can be more objective?
Thanks

Comment: It's not a tip, when you see you query in string format, you see that : `WHERE tlb_lining.id IS NULL`. So the ID you pass to the model is NULL. It cannot be more clear.

Comment: Ok but how to solve that in the query? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you need to return the `$query` result.

At the minute you are trying to return the result set of a variable named `$data` which I presume doesn't exist!!

Try changing `return $data->result();` to `return $query->result();`

Hope that helps!!